# Calculate round retail prices for opencart

Tags: opencart, rounding

Maybe someone has a clue. I want to round the retail prices to nice numbers in opencart.

Base calculation is: (which should produce € 1,50 - €2,00 - € 2,50 etc.)

```
        $price = sprintf("%.2f", round($pice * 2) / 2);
```

I thought I'd do it like this in controler/product/product.php but that isn't working. I don't want to edit all theme .tpl so it has to be done in the opencart code.

Now I have this, but I get values of €0.49 or €0.99

```
        $price_new = $this->tax->calculate($result['price'],                        $result['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax'));
        $price_new_1 = count($price_new , 2)/2-0.01;
    $price_complete = $this->currency->format($price_new_1);
    $spec_price_new = $this->tax->calculate($result['special'], $result['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax'));
    $spec_price_new_1 = round($spec_price_new, 2)/2-0.01;
    $spec_price_complete = $this->currency->format($spec_price_new_1);
        
    if (($this->config->get('config_customer_price') && $this->customer->isLogged()) || !$this->config->get('config_customer_price')) {
                $price = $price_complete;
            } else {
                $price = false;
            }
                    
            if ((float)$result['special']) {
                $special = $spec_price_complete;
            } else {
                $special = false;
            }
```

Older attempts which did not lead to a price:

```
        if (($this->config->get('config_customer_price') && $this->customer-                     >isLogged()) || !$this->config->get('config_customer_price')) {
           $price = sprintf("%.2f", round($this->currency->format($this-  >tax->calculate($result['price'], $result['tax_class_id'], $this->config-  >get('config_tax'))) * 2) / 2);
           
        } else {
           $price = false;
        }
              
        if ((float)$result['special']) {
           $special = sprintf("%.2f", round($this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($result['special'], $result['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')))* 2) / 2);
        } else {
           $special = false;
        }
```

I also tried it this way:

```
        // round price calculation
        $normaloldprice = $this->currency->format($this->tax- >calculate($product_info['price'], $product_info['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')));
        $newprice = round($normaloldprice * 2)/2;

        $specialoldprice = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($product_info['special'], $product_info['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')));
        $newspecialprice = round($specialoldwprice * 2)/2;

        $oldtaxprice = $this->currency->format((float)$product_info['special'] ? $product_info['special'] :                                                  $product_info['price']);
        $newtaxprice = round($oldtaxprice * 2)/2;
        // end round price calculation
                    
        if (($this->config->get('config_customer_price') &&           $this->customer->isLogged()) || !$this->config->get('config_customer_price')) {
            $this->data['price'] = $newprice;
        } else {
            $this->data['price'] = false;
        }
                    
        if ((float)$product_info['special']) {
            $this->data['special'] = $newspecialprice;
        } else {
            $this->data['special'] = false;
        }
        
        if ($this->config->get('config_tax')) {
            $this->data['tax'] = $newtaxprice;
        } else {
            $this->data['tax'] = false;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

for a clean and crisp solution, this module will do what you need.

http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=10351