# Round price to .99 via phpmyadmin on Opencart website

Tags: opencart

We have an online shop running opencart 1.5.6.4 and hoping to figure out a way of round the prices to the nearest .99. We just switched on "show prices with vat" and all our prices are now up 23%. I was hoping I could get the pricing looking a little bit better

For example:

Current Price: €608.85
New Price: €608.99

If there was a way of editing the table "product" and incrementing all the "price" values to end with .99, it would be really really helpful :-)

Thanks

Comment: *to the nearest .99* !== *incrementing all the "price" values to end with .99* - please be accurate in what you want to achieve. E.g. `18.25` shall be *rounded* to the nearest *.99* if it will be `17.99`, but *incrementing* would mean `18.99`. So?

Answer (score 1):

You can round up using `ceil` and then subtract a cent:

```
select ceil(2.20) - 0.01
```

In an update, you can do this:

```
update product
set
  price = ceil(price) - 0.01
```

Instead of `ceil` you can also select `round`, to round to the nearest whole number or `floor` to always round down. But beware: products that were, say, 0.20 will become -0.01 then.

If you only want to display nicely rounded prices in vat, but store them ex vat, then you'll have to do a calculation for that. 
(Crooked indenting to be able to squeeze comments in)

```
update product
set
  price = 
    round(
       -- Calculate the price incl VAT. Round it, and subtract a cent
       ceil(price * 1.23) - 0.01
       -- Round to whole cents.
       , 2 )
       -- Divide to calculate the price excluding VAT that belongs to the rounded price.
       / 1.23
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick reply, it does not seem to work, only seems to add .0.01 on every price and the same for .99.

Comment: also we were hoping to just make all prices, regardless of start figure to round up to nearest value if possible.

Comment: Rounding up works with `ceil`. The update statement that I posted should do exactly that. Round every product price up towards the nearest 99 cents. That is, if that price needs to be the price in vat. If the price is still *stored* as price ex vat, then the calculation is a bit different. I'll post that as well.

Comment: sorry a little confused, i do appreciate the help as well :-)

Comment: I think you mean that the price is stored ex vat, but displayed incl vat. In that case, you need to round the price including vat and calculate an unrounded price excluding vat from that rounded price. I've added an update for that. I don't know opencart, so I don't know how it stores its prices, so sorry if I didn't get it right at once.

Comment: it worked!! apart from anything that has VAT added on... is there a way to get over any "inc tax" prices? Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: How can you tell which prices have VAT, and which ones don't? Or maybe I don't fully understand your last remark.

Comment: Maybe interesting. On the right, a couple of other OpenCart questions are listed, among which this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11835177/calculate-round-retail-prices-for-opencart?rq=1